# How to move react native app from windows to mac machine

Tags: react-native

I have developed react native application on my windows machine, now I'd like to copy the application source files to mac os to generate ios app, can someone share the steps for this process.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the project as it is to the mac machine and follow the steps 
[build on device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)

Comment: ok will try it and let you know the exact steps, thank by the way.